# Defining custom types in template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, types, template-meta-programming

I found the following code in some video and I got very interested.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define LIST1(T1) Node<T1,Null>
#define LIST2(T1,T2) Node<T1,LIST1(T2)>
#define LIST3(T1,T2,T3) Node<T1,LIST2(T2,T3)>
#define LIST4(T1,T2,T3,T4) Node<T1,LIST3(T2,T3,T4)>

struct Null { };
template <int X, typename Next>
struct Node {
    static const int val = X;
    typedef Next Next_;
};

template <typename List> 
struct Sum
{
    static const int sum = List::val + Sum<typename List::Next_>::sum;
};

template <>
struct Sum<Null> {
    static const int sum = 0;
};

int main()
{
    cout << Sum<LIST4(2, 2, 3, 4)>::sum << endl;
}
```

My question is, what is the better way to do it? What other means do I have to do similar kind of parsing? The main problem I see is with the preprocessor directive used to define the type. Is there any other way to do so?

For example, I want to represent IP address same as above:

```
Sum<IP<120.100.10.20>>
```

which will parse the input.

Also if it's possible to take it from file, it would be much more useful. I think this kind of formatted data should be allowed to taken as type in TMP. How would I modify the code to support that?

**Edit** :: Adding another code which make me feel it will be useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#define LIST1(T1) Node<T1,Null>
#define LIST2(T1,T2) Node<T1,LIST1(T2)>
#define LIST3(T1,T2,T3) Node<T1,LIST2(T2,T3)>
#define LIST4(T1,T2,T3,T4) Node<T1,LIST3(T2,T3,T4)>

using namespace std;

// Highest bit in an IP address
template <typename List, int N, bool B>
struct highestBitSet
{
    static const bool b = List::val & (1 << N);
    static const int bit = highestBitSet<List, N - 1, b>::bit;
};

template <typename List, int N>
struct highestBitSet<List,N,true>
{
    static const int bit = N+1;
};

template <typename List>
struct highestBitSet<List, -1, false>
{
    static const int bit = 8+highestBitSet<List::Next_, 7, false>::bit;
};

template <int X>
struct highestBitSet<Null, X, false>
{
    static const int bit = 0;
};


int main()
{
    // Will print 0 
    cout << highestBitSet<LIST4(1, 0, 0, 0), 7, false>::bit << endl;
    // WIll print 31
    cout << highestBitSet<LIST4(0, 0, 0, 255), 7, false>::bit << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a poor man's (c++98 bound) solution for variadic template parameter lists. Welcome to the current decade.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Indeed, this looks about the same as what Andrei Alexandrescu does in his Modern C++ Design book for type lists.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Sorry i am not very much familiar with old thought and new implementations. Can you please guide me?

Comment: @KartikV _"Can you please guide me?"_ No, that's not the purpose of this site, and I'm not willing to do so via chat or eMail. Also it's already well [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Sorry if i have posted it wrongly, i am aware of variadic template. So is this way of programming not productive?

Comment: It's a waste of typing.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, what is the better way to do it? What other means do I have to do similar kind of parsing? The main problem I see is with the preprocessor directive used to define the type. Is there any other way to do so?

Using C++17's fold expressions, or C++14 `constexpr` if C++17 not available:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int... N> int_list { };

template<int... N> int_list<N...> list() { return {}; }

template<int... N>
int sum(int_list<N...>)
{
#if __cplusplus > 201402L
  return (N + ...);
#else
  const int vals[] = { N... };
  int sum = 0;
  for (auto v : vals)
    sum += v;
  return sum;
#endif
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << sum( list<2, 2, 3, 4>() ) << std::endl;
}
```

> For example, I want to represent IP address same as above:
>
> ```
>   Sum<IP<120.100.10.20>>
> ```
>
> which will parse the input.

You don't need a variable length list for an IPv4 address, it always has four components. And the code you showed doesn't do any parsing ... that would be a completely different problem. Passing four separate arguments to a macro or function like `LIST4(120, 100, 10, 20)` is completely different to writing `120.100.10.20` which isn't even a valid C++ token.

> Also if it's possible to take it from file, it would be much more useful. I think this kind of formatted data should be allowed to taken as type in TMP. How would I modify the code to support that?

Reading data from a file is a run-time effect, you can't combine templates (compile-time) with I/O (run-time).

Comment: This is really interesting. Can you also let me know if it is possible to load from file the list values. Like i have list of IP's in a file i want to use them to feed in to TMP. Is it possible?

Comment: what it takes to make this 120.100.10.20 valid in c++ as some type? Not a string. My point of asking the questions is that if it was possible to represent IP as type it will be really good. I guess it is not possible as it is like you said.

Comment: @KartikV he did show you how to turn an IP into a type. `int_list<120, 100, 10, 20>` is a different type than `int_list<216, 0, 0, 0>`.

Comment: Right, you can encode an IP address into a template, but why do you want to? If you do that then you can only ever use hardcoded IP addresses, as you can't read them from files or from user input or from the network. The only IP addresses that make sense to hardcode are things like 127.0.0.1 or 10.255.255.255 and do you *really* need a custom type and template meta-wankery just for that?

Comment: @user2296177 I already did the same in the example in my post itself.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I get your point, looks like there is no use case for it.